# Constrained Sum of Factorials

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial, multinomial-theorem

Consider the sum
$$S=\sum_{\substack{r_i>0,\\1\le i\le m\\
    r_1+...+r_m=n}}\frac{1}{r_1!...r_m!},$$
where $m,n$ are fixed, positive integers, and the $r_i$ are integers. If there were no condition that $r_1+...+r_m=n$, then this could be decomposed as
$$\sum_{\substack{r_i>0,\\1\le i\le m}}\frac{1}{r_1!...r_m!}=\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{r_i>0}\frac{1}{r_i!}=(e-1)^m$$
But with the condition $r_1+...+r_m=n$, I am unsure how to sum this. I suspect one could, for example, use
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n!}=e\frac{\Gamma(k+1,k)}{k!}-1,$$
where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function, but I am unsure how to proceed. How would one go about getting an expression for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a change of variables $s_i=r_i-1$ and apply the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Sum_of_all_multinomial_coefficients):
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{\substack{r_i>0,\\1\le i\le m\\
    r_1+\dots+r_m=n}}\frac{1}{r_1!\dots r_m!} \\
&=\sum_{\substack{s_i\ge 0,\\1\le i\le m\\
    s_1+\dots+s_m=n-m}}\frac{1}{s_1!\dots s_m!} \\
&=\frac{1}{(n-m)!}\sum_{\substack{s_i\ge 0,\\1\le i\le m\\
    s_1+\dots+s_m=n-m}}\frac{(n-m)!}{s_1!\dots s_m!} \\
&=\frac{m^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}
\end{align}